# How to return a Viewable object from httpPost

Tags: java, rest, web-services, httpclient

I am doing a http POST call in my Java application to a URL. I do this way since it is 2-way mutual authentication so I add custom SSL headers to the CloseableHttpClient instead of submitting a form from a jsp.

```
HttpResponse response = closableHttpClient.execute(httppost);
```

However the response presents a view if this call is Http 200. How do I get View Object out of response. Typically I would do something like this if the resultant is a different site.

```
return new com.sun.jersey.api.view.Viewable("/submitForm.jsp", null);
```

However since I add custom certificate related headers I am stuck with making the httpCall from Java code using client.execute().
Any thing I may be

Comment: Is that the apache http api you're using? If not, what is it? Can you show how you're *trying* to return it? Traditionally you just return a HttpResponse which represents a HttpEntity.

Comment: Yes apache http api. I would like to return a jsp like how I am doing in my code `return new com.sun.jersey.api.view.Viewable("/submitForm.jsp",null)`.  
However now I don't have a jsp page but instead I submit the form from inside my Java code using the `closableHttpClient' object. The http would render a view which I would like to return.